# How to prevent my terminal from printing last command?

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh

I have MacOS / iTerm2 / zsh setup.

After changing some settings, my terminal started to repeat last entered command. For example, if I'm in folder A, which contains folders B and C:

```
>>ls
ls
B  C
```

However, I want it to be:

```
>>ls
B  C
```

Where should I search for settings which can change it? I searched through `.zshrc` but didn't find anything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you've enabled "verbose" mode with for instance `setopt verbose` or `set -v` or `set -o verbose` or `options[verbose]=on`.

Unset it with `unsetopt verbose` or `setopt noverbose` or `set +v` or `set +o verbose` or `options[verbose]=off`.